# How to make code on backend accessible on frontend of Alfresco 4?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I wish to make classess and enums that are accessible in whole Alfresco (backend and frontend). How can I do that?

Thanks,
D

Comment: Build the jar, apply the jar to both wars, done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the code, implementing the classes as you wish. Place the JAR in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib.

If you want to make those classes available to server-side JavaScript running in the Alfresco tier, expose your Java services as JavaScript root objects. Look at the Alfresco source for an example, such as how the searchService or siteService are exposed.

If you want to expose the repository tier to the Share tier, write web scripts on the data tier and call those via HTTP from the Share tier. There are many resources available on writing web scripts and about 400 web scripts that ship with the product so there are plenty of examples.